# c client server not working when running on different machine

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to create a Client Server model that will run on different machines that are connected on the same access point(home network). The Client Server model works perfectly when running on the same machine but when running on different machines the Client request times out. My router firewall is disabled and I have tried to turn off Windows firewall on both machines but still the connection of the Client to the Server times out and never connect. The code is very simple and I am giving it above

My Server code is as follows

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
    The port number is passed as an argument */
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/types.h> 
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
 socklen_t clilen;
 char buffer[256];
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
 int n;
 if (argc < 2) {
     fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
     exit(1);
 }
 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
 portno = atoi(argv[1]);
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
 if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
          sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
          error("ERROR on binding");
 listen(sockfd,5);
 clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
 newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
             (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
             &clilen);
 if (newsockfd < 0) 
      error("ERROR on accept");
 bzero(buffer,256);
 n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
 if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
 printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
 n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
 if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
 close(newsockfd);
 close(sockfd);
 return 0; 
}
```

To execute compile

`gcc server.c -o server`

and run

`./server portnumber`

My client code follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sockfd, portno, n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;

char buffer[256],ip[20];
if (argc < 3) {
   fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
   exit(0);
}
portno = atoi(argv[2]);
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
    }
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
strcpy (ip,argv[1]);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);   
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR connecting");
printf("Please enter the message: ");
bzero(buffer,256);
fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("%s\n",buffer);
close(sockfd);
return 0;
}
```

To compile & execute

`gcc client.c -o client && ./client ipaddress portnumber`

My problem as I said is when running on different machines.

A start the server on the one machine like this

`./server 55555`

and then start the client on the other machine like this

`./client the_other_machines_ip_address 55555`

example `./client 192.168.1.65 55555`

and client show the message connection time out.

As I said I turn off the firewall on both devices and my router firewall is disabled.
Can anyone point me out what is going wrong.

PS: When I run the either the client either the server on the same machine but the one in VMware ubuntu system it works fine!

Comment: are you able to ping your machines from each other?

Comment: "*... client show the message connection time out ...*" this sounds like the client could reach the server, but the server's responses are not transferred back to the client. Try to ping the client from the server. If this fails adjust the routing.

Comment: @Icarus3 No my machines are not able to ping I am working on it right now to see what is the problem. When I made them ping I will try again. Any help on how to make them ping will be appriciated

Comment: Start looking into router's setting. see if it has something similar to AP Isolation enabled. In my home, I have wireless router setup with AP Isolation disabled and it is configured to allocate fix IP addresses to my all devices.

Comment: @AntreasKarakannas: See `man route` and `man ifconfig`.